# Best way for deploy angular.js application made with yeoman?

Tags: angularjs, web-deployment, yeoman

I´m building application SPA using angular.js with yeoman  which connect with a API RESTful   made in Java using spring-MVC . i´m begginer for deploy web applications in angular and so i want to know some  differents   alternatives or best practice , for example deploy in http-server as apache, inside war using application-server as tomcat , or another option or suggestions .

Thanks a lot for help .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Then your frontend code is production-ready, just run `$ grunt build`
and serve static resources produced by Yeoman (Grunt in fact) by the very same server that is responsible for providing the backend of your app.

take a look at [my answer to similar question, showing project structure and some necessary configuration for Yeoman & Spring-MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680962/1432478).

In some more advanced deployments scenarios, there might be a need for introducing load-balancing and you might need separate servers for the frontend and backend, but we are talking about basic config here.